# Widget/Chart needed in Azure DevOps for Work Done Analysis

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, project-management, workitem, agile-project-management

Ours is a service-oriented organization which handles multiple project at a time. We want to introduce Agile Methodology in our team to follow. But this methodology is not getting feasible our team. We tried to implement this by planning sprint 1 for 15 days sprint for a project, say Project A. But members allocated to complete this sprint's task, weren't able to complete it in 15 days, as they got shifted to some other projects B, C, D, E, F's priority tasks. In such case, the Project A deadline gets missed, and in turn we have to pay price for being in delay. We try not to miss date of delivery for majority of projects, but sometimes it does happen that due to many things on plate, we do forget the committed dates for project live.

We use Azure DevOps to manage the projects. We create Phase/Sprint to whichever projects its feasible. Currently there are total 100 projects on-board, senior mentoring + project managing team has only 3 people & members to do development/testing work is 18.
Each resource per day does works on 4-5 projects on average.

If the senior team asks the member to fill excel/csv sheet of work they did particular day, and import that sheet in Devops, then it will be easy for team to get their tasks on Devops board for on regular basis. But the senior members can't view work of all 18 members did for a day in a go. There can't click on 20-30 project's URL per day and check which work items were did by which member on a particular day or which work items are closed or in progress in particular sprint?

So they need a widget which provides consolidated data of all these 100 projects work items together.  I have used pivot table widget, in its y axis does fits 18 members name but its x axis fits only 25 projects and not more that that. On click in Others column option also I am not able to view 100 projects projects. Other than that in this table, I am not able to differentiate the sprint-wise task too. I used Sprint overview , sprint burndown, sprint analysis etc. widgets but these widgets only give current project's current sprint data and not overall 100 projects' various sprints' (sprint 1, 2, 3 etc.).
This data is useful as this chart can be passed on to upper management for team's performance analysis. How fast or slow they are in resolving the work items.

So please help me in providing a solution, is it possible for me to have a consolidated view of chart/widget, where I can view work items (bug-wise, feature-wise, task-wise, user story-wise, test case-wise) assigned for 18 member-wise for various projects which are resolved/active/close/open under their name for a particular Sprint 1, Sprint 2, Sprint 3 etc.

It will be grateful if somebody helps to resolve this issue, Thanks in advance.

[Pivot Table trail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBnK9.png)

[Sprint chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSQ5D.png)

Comment: Hi @Charlie, how are things going? Have you tried the the "Delivery Plans" feature? Is it helpful to you? Please have a try with it. Any update, feel free to tell us. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @BrightRan-MSFT , thanks for asking update. Yes I tried with Delivery Plans extension its working.  Although this solution only partially solves the issue, it doesn't give what we are actually looking. Still one senior member has to sit to create user story, because the work item  "Task" is only created by developers and  Delivery plans extension doesn't give list of "Tasks" under a particular user story. How can be Task included in Delivery Plans Module?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is not such built-in widget that can consolidate views for multiple work item types, multiple users, multiple projects, multiple work item states and multiple sprints on Azure DevOps.

I also searched and tried some related Dashboard Widget extensions from the [Marketplace for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=work%20item%20widget&target=AzureDevOps&category=All%20categories&visibilityQuery=all&sortBy=Relevance), but did not find any available extension can meet your demands.

You may need to develop a custom Dashboard Widget extension by yourself following your demands.

You can reference to the documentation about "[**Develop a web extension**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?view=azure-devops)" and "[**Extension samples**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/samples-overview?view=azure-devops)" to develop yourself Dashboard Widget extension.

Comment: Okay. I too couldn't find any fruitful widget in Market Place for Azure DevOps.  I will try with "Develop a web extension" method by coordinating with some developers team mates. At the same time, could you address a query - Even though if multiple user-wise or project wise is not feasible with any current widget/chart, but can you suggest any chart/widget which is currently present in Azure DeVops where I can just visualize only all sprint (multiple sprint-wise) work items together ?

Comment: Hi @Charlie, You can try the "[**Delivery Plans**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/review-team-plans?view=azure-devops&tabs=plans-preview)" feature of Azure Boards. It is an extension provided by Microsoft (see [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-plans)), and now it has been buit-in to Azure Boards on Azure DevOps.